# How to call the custom classes as a services in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, shopware

I want to call the custom classes without creating an instance because all classes have the dependency injection.

In the below code I wanted to call the ApiService class but just for the dependency injection
I need to create an instance of all of them.

```
 $tokenClientFactory = new TokenClientFactory();

    $tokenResources = new TokenResource($this->cache,$tokenClientFactory);

    $clientFactory = new ComlitixClientFactory($tokenResources);

    $apiService = new ApiServices($clientFactory,$this->cache);
```

I don't want to call the classes like that.

As I work on shopware so I could easily call the service through the shopware container like this:

```
$testApi = Shopware()->Container()->get('abc.xyz.client.token_resource');
```

I just need to initialize the class in services.xml class and would be able to call the service.

Is there any alternate way to do just like a shopware.

> OR

- Magento uses the container to call the services?
- How to call the classes without dependency injection.
- I don't want to use the class as a helper function.

Anyone, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Container directly is bad practise. You should inject the services which you need. See symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Comment: Where to put the service.xml file in Magento 2 Hierarchy?